# The limit of a function at point a limit point p

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Am I right in saying that for a function $f$ and a limit point $p$, $\lim_{x \to p}f(x)=f(p)$ if and only if $f(x)$ is continuous at $p$?

If that is the case then say if $\lim_{x \to p}f(x)\neq f(p)$ then we conclude the function is not continuous at $p$?

Comment: Yes, is just the definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add to that that, besides being a limit point, $p$ belongs to the domain of $f$ (itherwise, it makes no sense to mention $f(p)$). Othar than that, it's fine (except that I would say that $f$ is continuous at $p$, not that $f(x)$ is continuous at $p$).